# Filter search list not retrieving invisible paragraph

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to center horizontally and vertically the text on the headings of these lists named: *comunicados, training on the job, and documentos*. I've tried the following:

a) using a div, 
b) using the text-align function 
c) using the margin: auto function

Perhaps I'm using them incorrectly. I'm learning to code :P 
Please help

```js
var filter = document.getElementById('myInput');
var drinks = document.querySelectorAll('.des');

filter.addEventListener('keyup',function(e){
  var s = e.target.value.toLowerCase();
  drinks.forEach(function(el,i){
    if(s.length > 3){
       if(el.textContent.toLowerCase().indexOf(s) < 0){
        el.style.display = 'none';
       }else{
        el.style.display = 'block';
       }
     }else{
       drinks.forEach(function(el,i){
        el.style.display = 'block';
       });
     }
     
  });
});
```

```css
  #myInput{
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-size: 14px;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    margin-left:20px;
  }
  .list{
    float: left;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    list-style: none;
    margin-top: -1px; /* Prevent double borders */
    margin-left:20px;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: black;
    background-color:#f6f6f6;
  }
  
   .list li:nth-child(1){
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
  }
  
  #list1{
   width:25%;
  }
  
  #h1{
   background: #e65c00;  /* fallback for old browsers */
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #F9D423, #e65c00);  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
   background: linear-gradient(to right, #F9D423, #e65c00); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
   height:50px;
   font-size:20px;
   font-family:Segoe UI;
   text-align:center;
   border-radius:7px;
   }
  
  #list1 a{
   border: 1px solid #ddd;
   border-radius:7px;
   margin-top: -1px; /* Prevent double borders */
   padding: 8px;
   text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 18px;
   color: black;
   background-color:#f6f6f6;
   display: block;
  }
  
  #list1 li a:hover {
   background-color: #FCF3CF;
   }
  
  #list2{
    width:25%;
  }
  
  #h2{
   background: #00b09b;  /* fallback for old browsers */
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #96c93d, #00b09b);  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
   background: linear-gradient(to right, #96c93d, #00b09b); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
   height:50px;
   font-size:20px;
   font-family:Segoe UI;
   text-align:center;
   border-radius:7px;
   }
  
  #list2 a{
   border: 1px solid #ddd;
   border-radius:7px;
   margin-top: -1px; /* Prevent double borders */
   padding: 8px;
   text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 18px;
   color: black;
   background-color:#f6f6f6;
   display: block;
  }
  
  #list2 li a:hover {
   background-color: #b8ede2;
   }
  
  #list3{
    width:25%;
  }
  
  #h3{
   background: #36D1DC;  /* fallback for old browsers */
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to left, #5B86E5, #36D1DC);  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
   background: linear-gradient(to left, #5B86E5, #36D1DC); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
   height:50px;
   font-size:20px;
   font-family:Segoe UI;
   text-align:center;
   border-radius:7px;
   }
  
  #list3 a{
   border: 1px solid #ddd;
   border-radius:7px;
   margin-top: -1px; /* Prevent double borders */
   padding: 8px;
   text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 18px;
   color: black;
   background-color:#f6f6f6;
   display: block;
  }
  
  #list3 li a:hover {
   background-color: #D6EAF8;
   }
  
  p.invisible {visibility:hidden;
    display:inline;
    font-size:0.1px;
    text-align:center;
    }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<link href="CSS/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
 </head>
  
<body>

</br>

 <input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="Ingresa palabra a buscar">

 </br>
</br>
 
<ul id="list1" class="list">
  <li id="h1">COMUNICADOS</li>
  
  <li class="des"><a target="_blank" href="#">Comunicado 1 - Payroll 
   <p class="invisible">
   Payroll 
   </p></a></li>
  
  <li class="des">Paper2</li>
  <li class="des">Paper3</li>
</ul>

<ul id="list2" class="list">
  <li id="h2">TRAINING ON THE JOB</li>
  <li class="des"><a href="#">Training on the Job
   <p class="invisible">
   Training on the Job
   </p></a></li>
  
  
  <li class="des">TOJ2</li>
  <li class="des">TOJ3</li>
</ul>

<ul id="list3" class="list">
  <li id="h3">DOCUMENTOS</li>
  
  <li class="des"><a target="_blank" href="#">Procedimiento Atención Usuario VIP
   <p class="invisible">
   VIP
   </p></a></li>  
  <li class="des">Document2</li>
  <li class="des">Document3</li>
    
</ul>
</body>
<html>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is:

```
li.des {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```js
var filter = document.getElementById('myInput');
var drinks = document.querySelectorAll('.des');

filter.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
  var s = e.target.value.toLowerCase();
  drinks.forEach(function(el, i) {
    if (s.length > 3) {
      if (el.textContent.toLowerCase().indexOf(s) < 0) {
        el.style.display = 'none';
      } else {
        el.style.display = 'block';
      }
    } else {
      drinks.forEach(function(el, i) {
        el.style.display = 'block';
      });
    }

  });
});
```

```css
#myInput {
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 14px;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.list {
  float: left;
  padding: 0px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  list-style: none;
  margin-top: -1px;
  /* Prevent double borders */
  margin-left: 20px;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: black;
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
}

.list li:nth-child(1) {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

#list1 {
  width: 25%;
}

#h1 {
  background: #e65c00;
  /* fallback for old browsers */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #F9D423, #e65c00);
  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #F9D423, #e65c00);
  /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Segoe UI;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 7px;
}

#list1 a {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 7px;
  margin-top: -1px;
  /* Prevent double borders */
  padding: 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: black;
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  display: block;
}

#list1 li a:hover {
  background-color: #FCF3CF;
}

#list2 {
  width: 25%;
}

#h2 {
  background: #00b09b;
  /* fallback for old browsers */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #96c93d, #00b09b);
  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #96c93d, #00b09b);
  /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Segoe UI;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 7px;
}

#list2 a {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 7px;
  margin-top: -1px;
  /* Prevent double borders */
  padding: 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: black;
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  display: block;
}

#list2 li a:hover {
  background-color: #b8ede2;
}

#list3 {
  width: 25%;
}

#h3 {
  background: #36D1DC;
  /* fallback for old browsers */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to left, #5B86E5, #36D1DC);
  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #5B86E5, #36D1DC);
  /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Segoe UI;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 7px;
}

#list3 a {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 7px;
  margin-top: -1px;
  /* Prevent double borders */
  padding: 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: black;
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  display: block;
}

#list3 li a:hover {
  background-color: #D6EAF8;
}

p.invisible {
  visibility: hidden;
  display: inline;
  font-size: 0.1px;
  text-align: center;
}

li.des {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link href="CSS/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>

  </br>

  <input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="Ingresa palabra a buscar">

  </br>
  </br>

  <ul id="list1" class="list">
    <li id="h1">COMUNICADOS</li>

    <li class="des"><a target="_blank" href="#">Comunicado 1 - Payroll 
   <p class="invisible">
   Payroll 
   </p></a></li>

    <li class="des">Paper2</li>
    <li class="des">Paper3</li>
  </ul>

  <ul id="list2" class="list">
    <li id="h2">TRAINING ON THE JOB</li>
    <li class="des"><a href="#">Training on the Job
   <p class="invisible">
   Training on the Job
   </p></a></li>


    <li class="des">TOJ2</li>
    <li class="des">TOJ3</li>
  </ul>

  <ul id="list3" class="list">
    <li id="h3">DOCUMENTOS</li>

    <li class="des"><a target="_blank" href="#">Procedimiento Atención Usuario VIP
   <p class="invisible">
   VIP
   </p></a></li>
    <li class="des">Document2</li>
    <li class="des">Document3</li>

  </ul>
</body>
<html>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: This aligns the <li> elements. What I'm looking for is aligning the headers. Both horizontally and vertically